# C# SDL2 and async methods

Tags: c#, asynchronous, opengl, sdl

I have my SDL2 application written on C#. My application doing basic rendering and some entities logic. Because all my logic handles in synchronous way, I decided to move into asynchronous.

My entities has `Task TickAsync(float deltaTime);` abstract method to perform entity logic. My call stack looks like this:

1. `Task Main(string[]?);`
2. `await RunAsync(CancellationToken);`
3. `await ExecuteEntitiesAsync(CancellationToken);`
4. `await entity.TickAsync(float);`

My problem: Because I'm using SDL2 and OpenGL, these libraries needs to be worked in one thread (where SDL2 was initialized and where OpenGL context was created. As I know, when task is created, it executes in other context (can be executed in current thread or not). Because `RunAsync` is async method, drawcalls can be executed not in current thread (I initialized SDL2 in `Main` method). `RunAsync` must be async because it calls `await Task.WhenAll()` for all entities.

My question: How can I make async method to execute in current context/thread or synchronous?

Comment: You cant have `Task` and `Task` running on the same thread. They're made specifically to tell your application "Right go off do this somewhere else while I finish doing the next part, and when you're done notify me". I've never used the libraries you're using but that's the whole story of `asynchronous`.

Comment: @ThisQRequiresASpecialist, If `await` modifier telling "Show me what you've done", Is `.GetAwaiter().GetResult();` telling the same?

Comment: @TimurVafin I'm not sure I can answer that question. I'm not that advanced yet, I just know basics of `Tasks` and `Threading`. Read up on this post I found from 2020 could be of use to you on this task you're on. [Why is .GetAwaiter().GetResult() bad in C#?](https://www.nikouusitalo.com/blog/why-is-getawaiter-getresult-bad-in-c/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Because all my logic handles in synchronous way, I decided to move into asynchronous.

I'm really not sure if this is a good idea. Does `TickAsync` really have asynchronous work to do?

Assuming that this *is* what you need, then you can create a single-threaded `SynchronizationContext`, which is non-trivial. I recommend using the `AsyncContext` from my [AsyncEx library](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx). Then your (synchronous) `Main` can just call `AsyncContext.Run` and pass a delegate containing your top-level logic (e.g., `RunAsync`).

Comment: "Does TickAsync really have asynchronous work to do?" - No It has not, but someday It will.

Can you please show the code of single-threaded `SynchronizationContext`? How should I implement it?

Comment: The [code](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/tree/master/src/Nito.AsyncEx.Context) is in the link I posted.